# How to send/receive Messages on RFCOMM Terminal

Tags: terminal, bluetooth

I have connected to another Bluetooth device via RFCOMM.

Now i want to send/receive Messages, but just typing them into the Console won't send them.. where to do that?

[image]

Comment: This sort of looks like what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028953/sending-binary-data-over-bluetooth-rfcomm-spp-converts-0x0a-to-0x0d-0x0a